# Simplest way to redirect pages in PHP

Tags: php

I need ideas on how to redirect a ton of pages to the root page (/). I am currently using this code for every page request to check if it needs to be redirected.

```
switch ($url) {
 case '/test.htm':
 case '/test2.htm':
 ....
 ....
 ....
     $redirect='/'; break;
}
```

I will then use 301 redirect to redirect the page.

But the problem with this approach is that I have more than 1000 urls, and the current page will be checked with all of the 1000 urls in that list, which is both time and resource consuming. Any better approach?

Comment: What if you lookup the `$url` from a data store (probably a database would be easiest)

Comment: You can redirect using htaccess

Comment: You cab use associative array like this: $redirectList = ['test.htm' => REDIRECT_URL, 'test2.htm' => REDIRECT_URL]. And check if (isset( $redirectList($url))) {DO REDIRECT}

Comment: Can you turn it around?  Do "non-redirect" action for pages you don't want to redirect and redirect everything else by default.

Comment: you want all pages to redirect to your root?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess method for this:
First create a .htaccess file and add 301 redirection rule like

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.php http://www.example.com/rootpage.php
```

or you can also redirect based on pattern check of URLs. Full code would be like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

see  http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml for more details

Answer (score 0):

create pages `test1.htm.php` etc (one for each url you want to redirect) that themselves do the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the CASES that need to be redirected.. Verify against the values in array, if the value exists in array then redirect else do not.

In this way, you won't need to add new checks when you are adding new URLS for redirection.

You can use `in_array` to find whether the url is in array or not.
For details of `in_array` check out : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of urls in one variable by comma separeted and do a check like this

```
if((strpos($list_of_urls,$url) !== false))
{
     //Code to redirect
}
```